# how run express js project on secure shell?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

1.please explain how to create secure shell in express project?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var pg = require('pg');
app.listen(7207);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/Asset/css', express.static('Asset/css'));
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('Home');
});

console.log("Server Running on 7207 port........(192.168.1.29:7207)");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't create a secure shell via node application. But you can run your application in [secure shell (SSH)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) by the following steps.

1) Take any terminal emulator and SSH into machine by command `ssh user@ip_address`

2) Run your application by `NODE_ENV="myenv" node myapp.js`

You may create a [screen](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) before running application so that the application will be running even if you disconnect SSH session.

`screen -S myscreen` will create new screen.

Comment: Please explain more details